# Rotate controls in Java

Tags: java, android, controls, rotation

How to rotate some control in java? For example I want to rotate radiobutton for 90 or 180 degrees

How to do this on JAVA SDK for android developing?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably overkill, but JXLayer does all kinds of transformations, including rotation. (The demos are impressive, if a little wacky!)

- [JXLayer 4.0 demonstration by Piet Blok](http://www.pbjar.org/blogs/jxlayer/jxlayer40/)

EDIT: the OP was edited to include android. This probably doesn't work on Android.

Comment: Wow, its pretty obvious once you see that library; create a proxy which transforms inputs and rendering, then delegates to the actual control.  I don't know if the use of affine transform is optimized for 90 degree rotation; but his demo totally rocks (even if its a bit slow at full screen)